# How can I adjust the obfuscation of the Azure indoor map?

Tags: azure, azure-maps

How can I adjust the obfuscation of an Azure indoor map?
As per tutorial (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/how-to-use-indoor-module), the zoom level on load HTML is defined as:

```
new atlas.Map("map-id", {....
... zoom: 19,
        });
```

The indoor map will only show on zoomlevel 19 or a higher value.
If I scroll (zoom out) of the map or change the base zoomlevel value in the HTML,
the building details are immediately no longer visible, only an outline remains.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it only shows details at zoom levels 19+. I don't believe their is an option to change this currently, but it is being looked into.

Curious about the need here. Does your building cover a very large area?

Do you want to be able to zoom in past level 22? Is so add `maxZoom: 24` to the map options when loading.

Comment: It consists of a large complex of buildings, it would have been nice if we could see the contours of the roofs when zooming out, instead of only the bounding box. :)

Comment: I'll pass on the feedback.